# Getting error when browse the website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I have website on IIS and when I browse I get this error- 
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Someone told me register asp.net but I get this error when I run this below command in cmd.

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i



This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administr
ators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Win
dows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.e
xe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlin
k/?LinkID=216771.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of reasons why this could be happening.  And thousands of documents available through search engines that can guide you through the troubleshooting process.  Start there.

Comment: @Will please I edited my question, I hope this will help us to dialogues the problem.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you need to do. Read it.

Comment: If you use StackOverflow as the first step when troubleshooting you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @Will What do you mean I don't understand.  First I try to solve the problem if problem occurs then I post in stark overflow .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the 4.5 version of the .NET Framework. Try this solution: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/2736284/how-to-install-asp.net-4.5-on-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012

Comment: I tried but I am not able to find-Application development in web server-Do you have any idea where is application development ?  For Windows Server 2012 computers, enable "IIS-ASPNET45" using Server Manager, under "Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server ->Application Development -> ASP.NET 4.5".